# Order groups in grid layout

Tags: views

When I create a grid view, I can create groups of elements. However I have no control over the order of these groups. I can sort on the grouping variable, but that is not what I want. I want to specify the order, not sort alphabetically. The default is the order the groups were created which suggests reordering the database rows might work as a kludge. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What are the elements and what are you grouping on?

Answer (score 0):

The module [Draggableviews](https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) could be a solution here. It adds a table drag handler and a order field that is saved after you have rearranged the view. The same order field can then be used in another display if you want.